# MySQL !includedir not working

Tags: mysql

This is for documentation of a problem I ran into and solved.

I tried to use MySQL’s `!includedir` directive to include files in the `conf.d` directory, but it wasn’t working. I tried messing with permissions and everything. This was my config tree:

```
/etc/mysql
├── conf.d
│   ├── mysql.cnf
│   └── mysqldump.cnf
├── my.cnf
├── my.cnf.local
└── my.cnf.fallback
```

And my `my.cnf`:

```
[client]
port        = 3306

[mysqld]
local-infile = 0 
port        = 3306
server-id   = 1 
# more stuff.....

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M 

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M 
sort_buffer_size = 20M 
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

!include /etc/mysql/my.cnf.local
```

However, the specified `/etc/mysql/my.cnf.local` file wasn't being loaded. See below for the solution.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that on top of requiring a `.cnf` ending for files in `!include` (and `!includedir`), you also can't have extra dots. The solution was to change the filename from `my.cnf.local` to `my-local.cnf`.

Comment: Good spot and nice to see you got the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'd named the included file `/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf` and for some reason it wasn't loading.

Renaming to `/etc/mysql/conf.d/my-local.cnf` seems to have fixed it for me.

---

(Mysql 5.5.61 in docker)